# How can I refer to user-defined keys within glossary style definitions?

Tags: glossaries

Go to the Output section to skip directly to the problem.

The manual for the `glossaries` package is (somewhat) clear about creating custom styles using the predefined keys `user1, user2, user3, user4, user5, and user6` within style definitions:

For redefinition of `\glossentry` p.215

```
\glsentryuseri{##1}
\glsentryuserii{##1}
\glsentryuseriii{##1}
\glsentryuseriv{##1}
\glsentryuserv{##1}
\glsentryuservi{##1}
```

For redefinition of `\subglossentry` p.215

```
\glsentryuseri{##2}
\glsentryuserii{##2}
\glsentryuseriii{##2}
\glsentryuseriv{##2}
\glsentryuserv{##2}
\glsentryuservi{##2}
```

## Definition of `\glsentryuseri` in glossaries.sty

```
 \newcommand*{\glsentryuseri}[1]{%
   \@gls@entry@field{#1}{useri}%
 }
```

## Definition of custom storage key `\glsaddstoragekey` in glossaries.sty

```
\newcommand*{\glsaddstoragekey}{\@ifstar\@sglsaddstoragekey\@glsaddstoragekey}
\newcommand*{\@sglsaddstoragekey}[1]{%
  \key@ifundefined{glossentry}{#1}%
  {%
    \expandafter\newcommand\expandafter*\expandafter
     {\csname gls@assign@#1@field\endcsname}[2]{%
       \@@gls@expand@field{##1}{#1}{##2}%
     }%
  }%
  {}%
  \@glsaddstoragekey{#1}%
}
\newcommand*{\@glsaddstoragekey}[3]{%
  \key@ifundefined{glossentry}{#1}%
  {%
    \define@key{glossentry}{#1}{\csdef{@glo@#1}{##1}}%
    \appto\@gls@keymap{,{#1}{#1}}%
    \appto\@newglossaryentryprehook{\csdef{@glo@#1}{#2}}%
    \appto\@newglossaryentryposthook{%
      \letcs{\@glo@tmp}{@glo@#1}%
      \gls@assign@field{#2}{\@glo@label}{#1}{\@glo@tmp}%
    }%
    \newcommand*{#3}[1]{\@gls@entry@field{##1}{#1}}%
  }%
  {%
    \PackageError{glossaries}{Key `#1' already exists}{}%
  }%
}
```

## Custom Keys

I have tried adding custom keys both ways.

### Custom Storage Key Definition

```
% Add Storage Key (Store info)
\glsaddstoragekey
  {elementname}% key/value name
  {}% default value if not explicitly set
  {\macelementname}% custom command to access the value if required
```

### Custom Regular Key Definition

```
% Add Regular Key
%\glsaddkey
%  {elementname}% key/value name
%  {}% default value
%  {\glsmacelementnameentrytext}% no link cs (like \glsentrytext)
%  {\Glsmacelementnameentrytext}% no link ucfirst cs (like \Glsentrytext)
%  {\glsmacelementnametext}% link cs (like \glstext)
%  {\GLsmacelementnametext}% link ucfirst cs (like \GLstext)
%  {\GLSmacelementnametext}% link allcaps cs (like \GLStext)
```

## How can refer to custom keys (elementname) within style definitions?

Within the document itself, I would refer to it as `\macelementname {<glossID>}`

I've tried using:

```
\glsfieldfetch{##1}{elementname}{\test}
\test
```

### Working Example

Modified Definition of `tree`. See injection point in code. By the way, using `\macelementname{##1}` does not crash if the key is missing, it just ignores it. Also, I am not sure why this minimal example does not show the description of "testglossary:pickle" while my actual document does. Maybe I forgot something. *Update: Order of glsaddkey and glsaddstroragekey matters. Now the description is shown.*

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{fontspec}
 \usepackage[nopostdot,nogroupskip]{glossaries}


% Add new style
 \newglossarystyle{customtree}{%
   \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
     % setup environment theglossary
     {\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
      \setlength{\parskip}{0pt plus 0.3pt}}%
     {}%
   % have nothing after \begin{theglossary}:
   \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}%
   % have nothing between glossary groups:
   \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%
   % set how each entry should appear:
   \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
     \hangindent0pt\relax
     \parindent0pt\relax
     \glsentryitem{##1}\glstreenamefmt{\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} (INJECTION \macelementname{##1})}% Reason for glstreenamefmt
     \ifglshassymbol{##1}{\space(\glossentrysymbol{##1})}{}% if symbol, put it in parenthesis
     \space\glossentrydesc{##1}% the description
     \glspostdescription% the post description
     \space##2\par% the page refs list
   }%
   \renewcommand{\subglossentry}[3]{%\subglossentry{level}{label}{number list}
     \hangindent##1\glstreeindent\relax
     \parindent##1\glstreeindent\relax
     \ifnum##1=1\relax
       \glssubentryitem{##2}%
     \fi
     \glstreenamefmt{\glstarget{##2}{\glossentryname{##2}}}%
     \ifglshassymbol{##2}{\space(\glossentrysymbol{##2})}{}%
     \space\glossentrydesc{##2}\glspostdescription\space ##3\par
   }%
   \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{\ifglsnogroupskip\else\indexspace\fi}
 }

% Add Storage Key (Store info)
\glsaddstoragekey
  {elementname}% key/value name
  {}% default value if not explicitly set
  {\macelementname}% custom command to access the value if required

% Add Regular Key
%\glsaddkey
%  {elementname}% key/value name
%  {}% default value
%  {\glsmacelementnameentrytext}% no link cs (like \glsentrytext)
%  {\Glsmacelementnameentrytext}% no link ucfirst cs (like \Glsentrytext)
%  {\glsmacelementnametext}% link cs (like \glstext)
%  {\GLsmacelementnametext}% link ucfirst cs (like \GLstext)
%  {\GLSmacelementnametext}% link allcaps cs (like \GLStext)



 % Define Glossaries and Associated File Extensions
 \newglossary[tlg]{testglossary}{testglossaryd}{testglossaryn}{Test Glossary}
 \provideglossaryentry{testglossary:pickle}{%
  type={testglossary},
  name={pickle},
  description={
  A delicious cucumber.
  },
}


 \makenoidxglossaries % Required
 \begin{document}
 \glsaddall % add all keys
 \printnoidxglossary[type=testglossary, sort=letter,style=customtree]
 \end{document}
```

## Output

Note that after "INJECTION", we should see the value of the "elementname" key (`\macelementname{##1}`)
[image]

Comment: You need to use roman numerals for the user fields `\glsentryuseriv` ,`\glsentryuserv` and `\glsentryuservi`. Since these types of commands (including your custom `\macelementname`) are designed to be expandable, they don't produce any error messages if the entry isn't defined. You can wrap it inside `\glsdoifexists{label}{\macelementname{label}}` if you want an error on non-existence.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Thanks. Corrected. Also, another thanks for the tip to detect missing keys. That is potentially useful for me later.

Comment: You haven't used the key `elementname` in your entry definition, so it assigns the default value, but the default value provided in `\glsaddstoragekey` is empty, so `\macelementname{testglossary:pickle}` expands to nothing.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot wait wait wait that can't be the problem....it can't be.....oh i hope not

Comment: @NicolaTalbot It seems my code is working except for that mistake you pointed out. What idiot wrote that example code? I can't wait to try check my code on the real document. If this was my mistake I am going to kill myself (not literally).

Comment: Don't worry. These things happen. If it turns out that something's still wrong with the real document, you can always edit the question with an updated MWE.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Yep, this was basically the problem. Actually, it caused by having the key only appear in subglosses. Because my injection was in `\glossentry`, it never appeared. However, once I added the injection to  `\subglossentry`, it worked. This question should probably get closed up. Do you want to leave an answer or should I?

Comment: You can add an answer if you like to summarise each problem. (You solved your original problem of missing the reference in `\subglossentry`, so I think that's appropriate.) I don't think the question actually needs to be closed as it can still be helpful to others.